# Add Active State to Anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple 2 link toggle that I'm trying to add an `active` class to so I can style the active toggle.

HTML:

```
<div id="togglebuttons">
<span>Current Subscription</span>
<a href="#" class="member-button">Member</a>
<a href="#" class="trainer-button">Fitness Trainer</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#member").hide();
$("#fitness-trainer").hide();
$('.member-button').click(function(){

    $("#fitness-trainer").fadeOut(function() {$("#member").fadeIn();});
});
$('.trainer-button').click(function(){

    $("#member").fadeOut(function() {$("#fitness-trainer").fadeIn();});
});
});
```

Where would I add something like this

Comment: probably in a `<script>` tag in your document `<head>` ... is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

$("#member").hide();
$("#fitness-trainer").hide();

$('.member-button').click(function () {
    $("#fitness-trainer").fadeOut(function () {
        $("#member").fadeIn();
    });
    $(".trainer-button").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

$('.trainer-button').click(function () {
    $("#member").fadeOut(function () {
        $("#fitness-trainer").fadeIn();
    });
    $(".member-button").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```